# Certain Htaccess command is blocking my linux cron job

Tags: linux, .htaccess, cron, block

I have the following linux cron job added through my hosting control panel to replace wordpress internal cron job

wget -q -O - http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

However, certain commands inside .htaccess file is blocking my cron job from running every hour. After spending some time researching, I confirm they are came from these additional commands I added for protecting my site from query string exploits.

```
# BEGIN QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
# The libwww-perl User Agent is forbidden - Many bad bots use libwww-perl modules, but some good bots use it too.
# Good sites such as W3C use it for their W3C-LinkChecker.
# Add or remove user agents temporarily or permanently from the first User Agent filter below.
# If you want a list of bad bots / User Agents to block then scroll to the end of this file.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|\(|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%28|%3C|%3E|%00).*(libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/\*\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cgi-bin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} owssvr\.dll [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.opendirviewer\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} users\.skynet\.be.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*embed.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^e]*e)+mbed.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*object.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^o]*o)+bject.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\(|\)|<|>|%3c|%3e).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\x00|\x04|\x08|\x0d|\x1b|\x20|\x3c|\x3e|\x7f).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\./|\../|\.../)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \-[sdcr].*(allow_url_include|allow_url_fopen|safe_mode|disable_functions|auto_prepend_file) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
# END QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
```

I know if I just delete these commands, then everything should be alright. But, these commands could help me to reduce query string exploits which I got them from other site. Can you all help me to identify which part of the commands are the culprits?

Answer (score 0):

First condition is likely it, it's blocking requests from wget:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwww-perl|wget|...
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that could be the main culprit which stopped my linux cron job from running. But, I haven't tried on that. I got another suggestion from another site that taught me to use PHP rather than wget

Comment: By just replacing wget with PHP directive, I don't need to change anything on my htaccess file. So, that solves all of my problems!

Comment: You could also force wget to use a different user agent string, thus bypassing the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

My linux cron job is working now. I replace wget directive with PHP, which I got them from another site. But, I have another question here... Actually, I have two cron jobs which I set them to run at different interval (once per hour and once per three hours accordingly). If I don't replace wordpress internal cron job with linux cron, they should be able to run at different interval. But, after I replace them with linux cron job, I guess I would only be able to select one of the interval to run both of the cron jobs at the same time. And I also found out that no matter what interval I set to run the particular function in my php script (coded in my plugin files of course), they would follow the interval I set in linux cron directives. So, do I have to merge both cron jobs and use only one interval as it seems that linux cron only allow to to set one interval for that directive?

Comment: Could you post the actual command line you're using so others (e.g. me!) with the same problem can see what exactly to do?